# TRzDirectoryTree Set current directory

Tags: delphi

How to set current directory in TRzDirectoryTree component from raize components
i try

```
  dir.SelectByPath('c:\data');
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Directory property. It's not published so you can not set it via the object inspector (at least in the version i'm using)

```
RzDirectoryTree1.Directory := 'C:\Windows\System32';
```

Comment: thank's philipp i doesn't figure out the option because it's look grayed in the code completion is it the same for you [link]https://imgur.com/VWYGwM2

Comment: No. I guess you are on a newer Raize version. I don't use raize anymore though..

Delphi is hinting that TRzDirectoryTree is deprecated and i should use TRzShellTree instead.